# Reorder results from another query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM cars WHERE site = '5' 
   ORDER BY cost DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
)
ORDER BY time
```

How would I execute a sql query like this? So first it selects the 10 cars with the highest cost, THEN it reorders those 10 cars by what time they were added to the DB.

I tried to figure it out but I just cannot get a grip on the syntax :P

Comment: can you share your sample db

Comment: Just give the derived table its own alias. So `) x ORDER BY time`

Comment: It's a simple DB like. ID - time - cost - car - color, etc.

Comment: can you try this
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM cars WHERE site = '5' 
   ORDER BY cost DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
) as t
ORDER BY time

Comment: Yes that works, so simple - and so elegant. Thank you Chintan :)

Comment: yeah posted as answer

Answer (score 2):

Just give an alias to the sub-query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `site` = '5' 
   ORDER BY `cost` DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
)t
ORDER BY `time`;
```

Comment: I've been reading this should work, but in my query it does nothing.. The 10 most expensive cars does not get sorted by time, they are still sorted by cost only.

Comment: @Strawberry : Yes, you are right. The first sort will be on `cost` and the then `time`. It's my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
This query will give you the desired results
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM cars WHERE site = 5 
ORDER BY cost DESC LIMIT 0 , 10 ) as t ORDER BY time
```